# Run demo locally fails: Service 'consumer' failed to build

Tags: api-platform.com

When Tring to build the API-Platform demo has described on the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/api-platform/demo) the building appears to fail on PHP step:

```
Step 28/36 : RUN set -eux;  mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev;   composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd;  chmod +x bin/console; sync
 ---> Running in 7c9b0eb0fd97
+ mkdir -p var/cache var/log
+ composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev
Generating optimized autoload files (authoritative)
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
Generated optimized autoload files (authoritative) containing 4776 classes
+ composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
Executing script security-checker security:check [KO]
 [KO]
Script security-checker security:check returned with error code 1
!!                                                              
!!    The web service failed for an unknown reason (HTTP 403).  
!!                                                              
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
ERROR: Service 'consumer' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -eux;    mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev;   composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd;  chmod +x bin/console; sync' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I try the following commands:

```
docker-compose build
```

I opened an issue too https://github.com/api-platform/demo/issues/192

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think the service stopped ..

https://packagist.org/packages/sensiolabs/security-checker

use this instead

https://github.com/fabpot/local-php-security-checker